# Request to IIS resource protected with "Windows authentication" from localhost returns Unauthorized

Tags: windows, kerberos

I have a following problem accessing a resource protected with use of "Widows authentication" on IIS
One unprotected site "Anonymous authentication" is trying to access a resource available on the same IIS, but different site (I'm using HttpClient to make a Request and access it). The site with a resourse is protected using "Windows authentication" - Negotiate (kerberos).
The operation result is "HTTP Error 401.1 - Unauthorized". After hours of digging I discovered that the problem occures only on the server.
When I run my application using Visual Studio it works perfectly.

What could be a reason of such a problem?
I tried adding CredentialsCache containing valid password and login / using DefaultCredentials etc but the result is the same.
Runinng the site from a Visual Studio on a different computer on the same local network does not need any credentials.

The expected result is a raport. I'm accessing a resource that takes the parameters from json passed to a request and generates a raprort based on a parameters